# Automating xquery execution against multiple files with Saxon 9.6HE

Tags: xml, command-line, xquery, saxon

I have a query that specifies in a file the document to read.

I need to execute this query against many files, so I'd need something like passing the filename from the commandline.

I don't know how to do this. How can I solve my problem?

An example of my query file is

```
for $i in doc("myfile") 
return $i
```

and I'm running it with this commandline

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp "./tagsoup/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar:./saxon/saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Query -x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser  $1
```

Comment: Is there a common directory structure for all of these files? If so, consider passing in a directory path and using `collection()` to process the files.

Comment: @DanielHaley You are right, I added this to my answer.

Comment: the collection approach isn't feasible, however it is an interesting one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to pass the source document as the context item for the query. Change the query to

```
for $i in . return $i
```

(which simplifies to just ".")

and set the source document in the `-s:source.xml` option on the command line.

You can also declare external variables in the query and set them from the command line, for example

```
declare variable $uri external; doc($uri)
```

then

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -q:query.xq uri=source.xml
```

I guess from the question that you didn't manage to find the documentation for the Saxon XQuery command line: it is here:

http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xquery/commandline

Note that although this is the direct answer to your question, you will get much better performance using the collection() approach suggested by @DanielHaley, because it avoids the overheads of initialising the Java VM and compiling the query for each file that is processed.